# Recruiter may have missed my email

Tags: interviewing, email

I am in contact with a recruiter from a business that I would really like to work for. Last week we set up a phone interview over email. Just before the interview, he asked if he could postpone for an hour. I responded saying that was fine. The interview took place an hour later and it went well enough that I was asked to email a list of times that I could meet in person next week (this week now) for a programming interview.

Promptly after the interview I emailed the recruiter, thanking him for his time and providing my list of available times **in the same email thread as before**.

I haven't heard back. I realize that these things can occasionally move slowly, so it is entirely likely that he hasn't had the time to get back to me or that he hasn't been able to schedule the interview yet. But I am worried by the fact that I sent two consecutive emails in the same thread. I can see the possibility of him reading the unread email and seeing my response to his request to push the interview back and **missing my available times response**.

I don't want to miss the interview window (that he specified was this week).

Am I being overly paranoid or would it be appropriate to send another email along the lines of

> "Dear recruiter, I am worried that you may have missed my previous
>   email. Please excuse me and disregard if this is not the case. Here is
>   the previous email... "

Comment: Should my conversation go along the same lines as the example email in the question? `Sorry to bother you, just want to confirm that you received my email last week?`

Comment: Better: "Nudging this to the top of your inbox in case you were too busy last week."

Comment: They're recruiters. Missing emails is half of their job.

Comment: Agreed, this question is really about how to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not say

> "I am worried that you may have missed my previous email..."

or as suggested in the comments

> "Sorry to bother you..."

**Instead**, I would say something along the lines of

> "I'm following up on my previous email as my calendar is starting to
>   fill up for this week and I wanted to make sure I had availability."

Or something like that. You shouldn't be apologetic for following up.

Comment: Being apologetic or not might be culture dependent. I would indeed follow your suggestion, but I might imagine that there are cultures out that where being apologetic is expected.